# Making a HTTP POST Request in Swift 2

Tags: swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, httprequest

On [Google's Firebase website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/downstream#sending_topic_messages_from_the_server), in order to send downstream messages, I have to do an HTTP Post request. This is what it says to do:

> Sending downstream messages from the server:
>
> To address or "target" a downstream message, the app server sets to
>   with the receiving client app's registration token. You can send
>   notification messages with predefined fields, or custom data messages;
>   see Notifications and data in the message payload for details on
>   payload support. Examples in this page show how to send data messages
>   in HTTP and XMPP protocols.

**HTTP POST Request**

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Content-Type:application/json
Authorization:key=AIzaSyZ-1u...0GBYzPu7Udno5aA

{ "data": {
   "score": "5x1",
   "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1..."
}
```

How do I do this in Swift 2?

Answer (score 4):

*People down-voted this question, and it's a shame. I've been researching this topic for over 4 months now, and no other stackoverflow question/answer has helped me.*

Anyway, I've found the solution, specific to Google's Firebase Cloud downstream messaging. This sends a message to the Google server that pushes notifications to all users via a HTTP POST request.

Before doing any of the code below, be sure to follow the steps to setting up an iOS client for Firebase, installing all the correct pods and getting your certificates, provisioning profile, etc. [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in_firebase_messaging).

**View Controller:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let url = NSURL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")
    let postParams: [String : AnyObject] = ["to": "<Your registration token>", "notification": ["body": "This is the body.", "title": "This is the title."]]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.setValue("key=<Your Firebase Server Key>", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    do 
    {
        request.HTTPBody = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postParams, options: NSJSONWritingOptions())
        print("My paramaters: \(postParams)")
    }
    catch
    {
        print("Caught an error: \(error)")
    }

    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) in 

        if let realResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
        {
            if realResponse.statusCode != 200
            {
                print("Not a 200 response")
            }
        }

        if let postString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as? String
        {
            print("POST: \(postString)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

**App Delegate:**

```
var window: UIWindow?

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .Alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Okay", style: .Default, handler: nil))
    self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    FIRApp.configure()

    let notificationTypes: UIUserNotificationType = [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound]
    let pushNotifSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: notificationTypes, categories: nil)

    application.registerUserNotificationSettings(pushNotifSettings)
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    print("Device Token = \(deviceToken)")
    FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.Sandbox)
    print("Registration token: \(FIRInstanceID.instanceID().token()!)")
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {

    print(error)
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    // For push notifications sent from within the Firebase console
    if userInfo["google.c.a.c_l"] != nil
    {
        if let title = userInfo["google.c.a.c_l"] as? String
        {
            if let body = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"] as? String
            {
                self.displayAlert(title, message: body)
            }
         }
     }
     // For push notifications sent from within the app via HTTP POST Request
     else
     {
        if let title = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]!!["title"] as? String
        {
            if let body = userInfo["aps"]!["alert"]!!["body"] as? String
            {
                self.displayAlert(title, message: body)
            }
        }
     }
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    FIRMessaging.messaging().disconnect()
    print("Disconnected from FCM")
}
```

If anybody has any questions, please feel free to ask! I also know how to send to topics.

Thanks!

Comment: Using this solution will expose your server key which will compromise your app.

Comment: Please explain a better way to do it since you seem like you know what you're doing!

Comment: This is great, I don't know how it would compromise your app but I got it working on my app. Thank you!

Comment: @Timothy a safer approach would be to store the server key inside your database, then call it out when needed.

Comment: @Timothy I have been searching how I can do my post request to my firebase function but having an issue.  I have two variables that need to be passed to the function (index.js) uid & email - then it gets passed to PayPal for a payout.  any idea how I can do it?  see my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53773085/error-when-running-method-the-data-couldn-t-be-read-because-it-isn-t-in-the-cor ~or~ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53755879/how-to-send-a-post-http-request-to-a-server-using-swift

Comment: @Timothy Hi I'm struggling sending a notification to a topic and the error I get is `POST: {"error":"InvalidParameters: Bad topic or filter provided"}`. As you offered to help could you please check my question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51149628/invalid-topic-value-provided-while-sending-fcm-to-a-topic ? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

**Solution Update**

**Swift 4** + further insight on how to tweak the FCM in Swift

Locate your server key at **Project Settings > Cloud Messaging > Server Key**

[image]

```
func swiftHttpPostRequest(){ 


let serverKey = <Server Key> // AAAA8c3j2...
let partnerToken = <Receiver Token> // eXDw9S52XWoAPA91....  
let topic = "/topics/<your topic here>"  // replace it with partnerToken if you want to send a topic 
let url = NSURL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send") 

let postParams = [
                   "to": partnerToken,
                   "notification": [
                   "body": "This is the body.",
                   "title": "This is the title.",
                   "sound" : true, // or specify audio name to play
                   "click_action" : "", // action when user click notification (categoryIdentifier)
                  ]] as [String : Any]

   let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("key=\(serverKey)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
    request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

  do {
        request.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: postParams, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions())
        print("My paramaters: \(postParams)")
    } catch {
        print("Caught an error: \(error)")
    } 


let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
    if let realResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
        if realResponse.statusCode != 200 {
            print("Not a 200 response")
        }
    }

    if let postString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue) as String? {
        print("POST: \(postString)")
    }
}

     task.resume()
}
```

Comment: Many thanks. I was getting crazy sorting this out. Your answer mede me realise that I was using the wrong Server key, and also solved my sending function. Many thanks again.