# HTTP Post in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, http, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've been trying to send an HTTP post request to the Firebase Cloud Messaging Server. This is the code I've been working with, and I'm getting the following response. According to the Firebase docs, the message should have sent, except that it's not showing up when I send it to my devices, not in the background, nor in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`. Why wouldn't the message be showing up?

```
Body:Optional({"multicast_id":9176652856657890066,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1470318910131254%0753194407531944"}]})

Error: nil
Success: Optional(1)
```

Code Below:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send")!
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData
        let dictionary = ["notification":["title":"BBM","text": message,"project_id": "marketplace-management","registration_id":token!]] as AnyObject
        do {
            try request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: .PrettyPrinted)
        } catch {}
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("key=myKey", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
            print("Response: \(response)")
            let strData = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            print("Body: \(strData)")
            print("Error: \(error)")
            var json = NSDictionary()
            do { json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableLeaves) as! NSDictionary } catch {}
            let parseJSON = json
            let success = parseJSON["success"] as? Int
            print("Success: \(success)")
        })
        task.resume()
```

Comment: "it doesn't seem to be working" - Please edit your question to include the exact error messages that you received. Also, show us what the `response` was (the status code, in particular, helps diagnosing what's going on).

Comment: very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463676/making-a-http-post-request-in-swift-2/37484064#37484064

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    let dictionary = ["notification":["title":"","text": message,"project_id": "myProjectID","to":token]]
    print(dictionary)//["notification": ["title": "", "project_id": "myProjectID", "to": "12", "text": "message"]]
    do {
        try request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dictionary, options: .PrettyPrinted)
    } catch {}
```