# Making a simple HTTPS POST request with params in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I cannot for the life of me figure out this problem. And I hope you guys can.

I want to send a username and a password over a HTTPS POST. Problem is, I cannot make it work.

The code I am trying to make work right now is:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import PlaygroundSupport

let url:URL = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/myAPI")!
let session = URLSession.shared

var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData

let paramString = "username=Pleasework&password=itwont"
request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) {
    (
    data, response, error) in

    guard let data = data, let _:URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
        print("error")
        return
    }

    let dataString =  String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    print(dataString ?? "Got nothing")

}

task.resume()
```

Looking at my server logs, this request goes through, but it is supposed to create a file containing said params. I tried using a Chrome extension called "Request Maker", and the file was created. (The file is created with PHP, and is irrelevant to this question)I found that the file was only created once the content type was specified, so I tried that in Swift.

I am using Swift 3 and Xcode 8, I hope you guys can help me send a simple post request with a content type to a URL, all of the other answers on Stackoverflow have not helped me.

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful to see what the server is returning, does it return any error code? What is the response you are getting?

Comment: Also, I recommend you use alamofire for POST requests in iOS as it simplifies the workflow.

Comment: The servers logs show nothing out of the ordinary

Comment: Not related, but you need only to *guard* the error. If `error` is `nil`, `response` and `data` are guaranteed to be non-`nil`. And print the real **error** rather than the literal string `"error"`.

Comment: Woah! Just checked, definitely server errors! `[Tue Dec 13 21:01:33.950336 2016] [:error] [pid 22311] [client 1 myip:and port] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: username in /var/www/html/myAPI/index.php on line 2`
                                                                                                                   `[Tue Dec 13 21:01:33.950462 2016] [:error] [pid 22311] [client myip:andport] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: password in /var/www/html/myAPI/index.php on line 4` So it seems as though the server is not getting the POST data

Comment: Do you send `"username=Pleasework&password=itwont"` string? If you send something different, it can contain unescaped characters.

Comment: That is what I send yes, this is my first day of Swift, so this code is shamelessly copy pasted, sorry

Comment: I see there was an answer, but it was deleted :(

Comment: very helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463676/making-a-http-post-request-in-swift-2/37484064#37484064